# Checkbox that adds a class to tr in which it is located

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Structure of my table looks like this. How to make that if the input is checked it will add a class "selected" to < tr >  in which it is located ? And if the checkbox will be unchecked it will remove class "selected" from < tr > ? Please help me :)

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><img src="../gallery/thumbnails/1.png" alt=""></td>
    <td>tryb</td>
    <td>png</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><img src="../gallery/thumbnails/2.png" alt=""></td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>png</td>
</tr>
[..]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You bind an onchange event to the checkbox:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('selected', this.checked);
}).change(); // manually trigger change after the binding
```

Each time the checkbox changes, you set the parent row to selected based on the checked status.

Comment: But if checbox has parametr "checked" <input checked type="checkbox"> it's doesn't work. I mean after page refresh < tr > doesn't have "selected" class:(

Comment: @user3261158 If loads with `checked` on the tag, that isn't being set via an `onchange` event. You need manual `onload` logic to handle the initial render of the page, or you need to manually trigger a change after the binding. Answer updated.

Comment: @user3261158, Just use `$(':checkbox').change(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('selected', this.checked);
}).change();` that will take care of it

Answer (score 0):

This is easy.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    if(this.checked)
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass('selected');
    else
        $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
$(':checkbox').change(function () {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('selected');
});
```

References:

- [toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)
- [change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/)